# No more "Build a retail/food/... level"?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Since the last update, the emperor doesn't ask me to build a certain type of level anymore, he only wants me to build any kind of level I want.

Is it the same for you ?

Because I like to only build levels the emperor asks me for, I like roleplaying...

Answer (score 1):

Past the first several missions (at least in the iPad version), he stops asking you to build specific level types and only asks you to build levels of (any) type.

Comment: Same for the Android version. In the beginning, missions form a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The Emperor's missions are seemingly randomly generated. But, of late most of the missions have asked me to build any type of level in varying quantities.

This does not mean that he won't ask you to build a different type of level later.